# Burninate the "visit" tag

Tags: discussion, tagging, burninate

There is a tag called [visit](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visit).  But practically every question on Travel.SE is about visiting some place, so this tag is useless.  The questions with that tag seem to be a random mix with no particular theme.

I suggest that it be burninated and/or blacklisted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Done, all gone. The tag will tag (I believe) a week to vanish properly if it has no usage.

Answer (score 5):

I approve. Let's remove it from all questions (mod tools don't let me do it with one click, unfortunately).

Answer (score 0):

Works for me.  It's hard to imagine a useful usage case for it.